# Android - How to prevent the keyboard in the entire device

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm preparing a security application for parents who wants to track their kids activities. The requirement is that, if the device is moving (examples like driving) at the speed of 10 miles per hour, keyboard should be deactivated in the entire device such that, they should be prevented from doing any typing activities (even in messages, browsers, dialing phone numbers etc). 
I can write background activity to track the speed at which the device is moving. How can we prevent the keyboard completely in the device?